# How to debug why SSLSession.IsValid fails in Android?

Tags: android, ssl

I have a SSL client certificate .pem file. This file works fine when loaded from my C++ client via X509_load_cert_file() method.

Now, I am trying to load this file using the following code:

```
    InputStream caInput = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cacerts);
    java.security.cert.Certificate ca;
    try {
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    } finally {
        caInput.close();
    }
    ...
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
```

However, generateCertificate() throws an exception that the input file does not have ASN.1 sequence identifier.

The .pem file contains a bunch of certificates. I edited the file, removed the beginning comments and left just the first ---BEGIN CERTIFICATION---/---END CERTIFICATE--- pair. With this change, generateCertificate() does not give any error. However, my subsequent call to SSLSession.IsValid() return false.

Can someone please suggest what is it that I could be missing? Perhaps the rest of the certificates also need to be loaded in the keystore. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do need to be loaded. You should be generating a certificate *chain*. You're using the wrong API.

If you're asking about `SSLSession.IsValid()` you should exhibit some code that calls it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please point me an example on how to load a certificate chain from a multi-certificate .pem file?